# Given a set of geometrically independent points if we add a point outside of the plane spawn the set the new set is still gometrially independent

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

If ${a_0, ..., a_n}$ is geometrically independent, and if $w$ lies outside of the plane that these points spawn, then ${w, a_0, ..., a_n}$ is geometrically independent.

I tried doing this assuming $w$ would be in the plane and arriving to the set not being geometrically independent but was told this was not the correct aproach.

Now I assume we have $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}t_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}t_ia_i + t_{n+1}w = 0$ and I need to show that $t_1 = ... = t_{n+1} = 0$

If I make $t_{n+1} = -\sum_{i=0}^{n}t_i$ then I can get $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(a_i-w)t_i = 0$ and I also know that shwoing that the vectors $a_i - w$ are linearly independent would also work but I don't know where to go. I'm also not using yet that the $a_i$'s are geo indep.

I can tell this should be easy enough but any hint that points me into the right direction would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Break into cases depending on whether $t_{n + 1} = 0$ or not.

Comment: @ronno you are right if $t_{n+1}=0$ it becomes clear after using the gometric independence of the first set but if I assume its not 0 will I arrive to a contradiction?

Comment: If it's not zero, you can divide by it and solve for $w$, use this to show that $w$ is on the plane of the $a_i$.